# wxPython Splash Screen Trouble

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, splash-screen

I am working on a GUI for motor control, for which i will be loading huge data initially. Hence i want to add a splash screen to it. But do i need to fix the time out duration of the splash screen a priory? I would like the splash screen to disappear 2 seconds after the whole loading is done. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxsplashscreen.html#wxsplashscreen) you can pass in the style `wxSPLASH_NO_TIMEOUT` to prevent the splash screen from timing out automatically.  You'd need to have something in your other code that triggered its OnClose handler when you were ready for it to go away.

-- Edited --

The style `wxSPLASH_NO_TIMEOUT` is imported from wxPython._windows, which is deprecated.  It still works on my system in python 2.6 and 2.7, but you actually probably want to use this:

```
from wx._windows import SPLASH_NO_TIMEOUT
```

Then, in the milliseconds argument to SplashScreen you can use -1 like so:

```
mySplash = SplashScreen(myBitmap, SPLASH_NO_TIMEOUT, -1, myParent)
```

Later, when you've finished loading, call `mySplash.Destroy()` to clear it off the screen.

Comment: Don't forget about AdvancedSplash. That's an option too. See wx.lib.agw.advancedsplash or the demo.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, Please guide through the code for advanced splash screen if possible

Comment: There's a full example in the wxPython demo